# Tool Tip CSS not showing

Tags: html, css

My CSS code looks like this so far:

```
  .tooltip{display:inline;position:relative}
  .tooltip:hover{text-decoration:none}
  .tooltip:hover:after{
   background:#111;
   background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
   border-radius:5px;
   bottom:18px;
   color:#000;
   content:attr(title);
   display:block;
   left:50%;
   padding:5px 15px;
   position:absolute;
   white-space:nowrap;
   z-index:98
  }
  .tooltip:hover:before{
    border:solid;
    border-color:#111 transparent;
    border-width:6px 6px 0 6px;
    bottom:12px;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    left:75%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:99
   }
```

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<p style="color:black;"><a href="#" title="Sample tooltip" class="tooltip">Link</a><p>
```

For some reason, nothing is appearing. Does it have to do with the color of my text or how the CSS code is structured?

Comment: how about assigning the `tooltip` class on a `<div>` ?

Comment: That did work, but now my box is not showing. The link is visible though

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/NYmTL/

This fiddle seems to look fine with your code.  I changed `color: #000` to `#FFF`.  Black on black isn't very visible.

Comment: I changed the code to have a div in front of the p tag and the link is visible. The only problem now is that the tool tip box is not showing

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by fiddle. The only part of the box that is showing is the black triangle

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with your code, so I can see what your issue is.  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: how can i make a jsfiddle with my code? i followed your link that you provided and it works on that page, but on mine it doesnt.

Comment: All I changed with your posted code was the color of the font on your tooltip to white, as stated.  If you have more issues, make a fiddle demonstrating your issue as explained here: http://css-tricks.com/seriously-just-make-a-jsfiddle/

Comment: i changed the color too, but if i remove the div, the link doesnt show and the box doesnt show either

Comment: I entered everything i had on jsfiddle and it works perfectly fine there, but i dont know if its my css or how everything is structured

Comment: There is no div in the code you posted.  I'm not sure how you continue you expect someone to be able to help you without posting more code.  If it works in isolation on jsfiddle, the problem is likely elsewhere.